# Why does CType throw Invalid Date Exception

Tags: vb.net

In this sample code, CType returns 15th February on some computers (correct),
but on others it throws an exception,
"Conversion from string "15/02" to type 'Date' is not valid."

I thought it could be the CurrentUICulture, but that seems to have no effect.
My CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture are en-AU,
and on the machine that gets the exception,
CurrentCulture is en-AU
and CurrentUICulture is en-US,
but setting CurrentUICulture to en-AU does not resolve the issue.

So what affects CType?

```
Console.WriteLine("15/02 -> {0}", CType("15/02", Date))
```

Comment: Just a recommendation, if you have specific date format to parse as `Date`, you should use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` methods because both methods have `CultureInfo` setting.

Comment: Works for me in it-IT locale:
`15/02 -> 15/02/2019 00:00:00`
In your case it probably is interpreted as 2nd day of 15th month, which clearly throws up an error.
Try: `Console.WriteLine("15/02 -> {0}", CType("02/15", Date))`

Comment: Ctype seems to work. DateTime.Parse also with en-AU: https://dotnetfiddle.net/PiTe2z

Comment: Setting `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-AU")` could *solve* the problem. Instead creates another. Now you're culture-dependent. You should use `Date.TryParseExact(...)` and provide the exact format of this date: "dd/MM". Most probably, you should take care of the reason why you're parsing such a thing. If it's user input (since Australia has that DateTime format), use the provided tools (DateTimePicker, for example), to accept user input, using `InvariantCulture` as the predefined format.

Comment: Meaning, you only use `CurrentCulture` or `CurrentUICulture` (depending on the application functionality), to **present** the DateTime object in string format, because users want/need to *see* a specific format applied to the DateTime object. But you, internally, must deal with the DateTime object, not with its string representation. Ever.